# Check/Uncheck multiple checkboxes inside TableLayout

Tags: c#, android, checkbox, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a `TableLayout`; first column of the first `TableRow` is a `CheckBox`.  The `TableLayout` and the first `TableRow` are created in the `.axml` file.  I create and populate the rest of the `TableRows` in the `.cs` file.  The first column of each programmatically created `TableRow` is also a `CheckBox`.

Using the `CheckBox` in the first `TableRow` I would like to Check/Uncheck all programmatically created checkboxes.

In a Windows Forms application I would do this by gathering the checkboxes into an array and iterating through the array to set the checked property on each.  In my Android app I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: you can extend the `checkbox` class too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over all `TableRows` inside your `TableLayout`, find your checkboxes and checking/unchecking them. To do so, add a listener to the click event of your first checkbox that does something like this:

```
//Number of TableRows
var count = tableLayout.ChildCount;
//Position of you checkbox inside each TableRow
//TODO: make this a constant outside the listener method
var checkBoxPosition = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) {
    var tableRow = tableLayout.GetChildAt(i) as TableRow;
    if (tableRow != null) {
        var checkBox = tableRow .GetChildAt(checkBoxPosition) as CheckBox;
         if (checkBox != null) {
             //TODO: Use state of the main checkbox here
             checkBox.Checked = true;
         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  The only thing I did differently was to change the 0 in the `for` loop to a 1.  The `CheckBox` in the first `TableRow` triggers the loop and in my opinion, doesn't need to be handled.

Comment: I did, and once my reputation increases a bit, the score will change. :)